# How to change a doctype in HAML for selected layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

**How do you change doctypes in HAML for one particular view layout?**  All other pages for the system need to remain HTML5, however I'm needing a particular type for one special exception.

On Rails 3.1.x I've attempted several different ways to change my doctype from 5 to 4.01 to no avail.  I've looked at the following for guidance: http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#doctype_

It seems as though I cannot force the `:format` option within a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following workaround?

```
# in the top of application.html.haml
- if @use_4_01
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
- else
  !!!
```

Set somewhere in controller `@use_4_01` and you'll get this old doctype.

Comment: Very good, thanks for that.  I did not realize that you could simply insert a doctype without special provisions at the top of a HAML doc.